# Convert Issue to task

Tags: attask, workfront-api

Using workfronts API I am trying to figure out how to convert an issue to a task.  I have attempted to use the action method moveToTask of the ISSUE object, but this doesn't seem to be work.  It appears to be used to move an issue to under a task.  Does anybody know how to do this?  Additionally does anybody know where documentation exists on how to use their action methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is little/no documentation available directly from Workfront, unfortunately.

The conversion from an Issue to a Task isn't actually done by a single method call. It's actually creating a brand new task and copying over data (name, description, custom fields, etc.) and once the new task is completed it sets the resolving task ID, resolving object type, and resolving object ID within the issue. The issue remains intact and is simply closed out automatically when the resolving task is closed.

So you'll have a multi-step process of 1) create the new task and copy over basic fields, 2) attach custom form(s) if available, 3) fill out custom fields if needed, and 4) update issue with task ID and resolving details.

Comment: I understand how you do this now.  However how do you know what fields map to where.  What I did to determine this was did a get of a task and an issue and then sorted the fields alphabetically in EXCEL.  However I am making an assumption that they named the fields the same.    Did you implement this?